# Accesing an index in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
a <- c(130, 125, 80, 38, 24, 18, 15, 19, 23, 16, 16, 8, 13, 6)
b <- c(700000, 400000, 120000, 12000, 1600, 450, 194, 130, 114, 113, 46, 25, 13, 8)

df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I want to find the differences within the data frame ( for example, `130-125`, `125-80`, etc.)

Can I do that with a data frame or should I convert it to a vector / matrix?

Gracias

Comment: You can use `diff(a)`.  If it is within the dataset, `with(df, diff(a))`

Comment: If you use akrun's method don't forget to switch the sign `-diff(a)`

Answer (score 1):

use this function:

```
diff(your_data, lag)
```

with `lag` here in your situation is 1.

```
diff(a, 1)
```

your can use data frame object, use `apply` function to apply diff through all the columns.